# How can I get the list of all files that are sourced by bash?

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a way to find out all the files that are sourced by bash?

Alternately, is there a single point of entry (or a first point of entry) where I can go to follow and find this information by adding a `set -x` at the top?

(By single point of entry, I do not mean ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile because some other file higher in the source chain tells bash to load these above files in the first place).

Answer (score 20):

Reviving this question because there is an automation for this:

Execute bash and carve it out of the output. `-li` is login interactively, `-x` prints out what bash is doing internally, and `-c exit` just tells bash to terminate immediately. Using `sed` to filter out the `source` command or the `.` alias.

```
/bin/bash -lixc exit 2>&1 | sed -n 's/^+* \(source\|\.\) //p'
```

Comment: do notice that this does not show `source` calls using `.` alias.

Comment: added support for `.` alias

Comment: Nice! Surprised it took a year and a half to answer the first part of a 2-part Q. The other answers contain valuable info, but they dont catch the files sourced / included by the user. For some users, the latter is an ocean with a few `.bashrc` teardrops in it.

Comment: This is a god-sent answer. Awesome.

Answer (score 6):

There is no easy catch-all answer here, it depends on the combination of login/interactive attributes.

A login shell will source `/etc/profile`, and only the first one it finds among `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`. You could call these independent points of entry: `/etc/profile` doesn't need to explicitly source one of the others, it's `bash` that does it.

For non-login interactive, you have `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`, again independent.

For non-login non-interactive, the single point of entry is `$BASH_ENV`, if defined.

You can find the official description at the GNU Bash manual under [Bash startup files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files).

Answer (score 4):

There are several places where the process to load all startup files start.

The [table in this link](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/) will make it clear:

```
Interactive login          /etc/profile
Interactive non-login      /etc/bash.bashrc
Script                     $BASH_ENV
```

Understanding `login` as either an Interactive login or a non-interactive shell called with the option --login. From `man bash`:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the `--login` option, it first reads and executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists.

However, the most common call to an interactive shell is `su - $USER` which use a `-` as the first character of the command called (not `--login`).

That is the default.
Nothing prevent you from editing those files and add in /etc/profile something like:

```
if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
    source /etc/bash.bashrc
fi
```

Which will ensure that `/etc/bash.bashrc` would be sourced in all cases of `Interactive` shells.

Care should be taken to avoid duplicating variables or actions (sourced in both files). Defining a variable and checking that it has been already set before some actions would make this process more reliable.

The starting point for scripts, from the point of view of bash, is the variable `$BASH_ENV` which has to be set in the environment *before* bash is called. That expands the search to other shells or programs that may call bash. There is no single definitive solution in this case, only what is the usual practice.

The usual practice is to **not** use $BASH_ENV at all, so bash would start with all the compiled-in options only.

Comment: The interactive attribute does not matter for login shells: `env -i bash -lc 'echo $PATH'` will use a non-interactive login shell, which reads the profile files.